# How to apply Fourier convergence theorem to $f(x)=x$ in $-2<x<2$?

Tags: fourier-series

The Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ in the interval $-2<x<2$ with $f(x+4)=f(x)$ is given by

$$f(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)$$

The Fourier Convergence Theorem says that

$$\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)= \begin{cases}
                                   f(x) & \text{for all $x$ where $f$ is continuous} \\
                                   \frac{1}{2} & \text{for $x$ where $f$ is discontinuous} 
  \end{cases}$$

How to show the above piece wise equality holds?

Here is the graphical representation of the original function $f(x)=x$ (green) and its Fourier series (red),
[image]

The Fourier Convergence Theorem

> Theorem: Suppose $f$ and $f^{'}$ are piecewise continuous on the
>   interval  $−L \leq x \leq L$. Further, suppose that $f$ is defined
>   elsewhere so that it is periodic with period $2L$. Then $f$ has a
>   Fourier series whose coefficients are given by the Euler-Fourier
>   formulas. The Fourier series converge to $f (x)$ at all points where
>   $f$ is continuous, and to $$\frac{1}{2}\left[\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{-}}
> f(x)+\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{+}}f(x)\right]$$ at every point $c$ where
>   $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: What theorem ? I know a theorem when $f$ is piecewise $C^1$, with the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel). You write that $f_N(x) = f \ast D_N(x)$ and show the convergence.

Comment: Otherwise, in this particular case, you can show that $-\log (1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ for any $|z| < 1$ and by continuity also for $|z| = 1, z \ne 1$. Taking the imaginary part, you have your Fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ is continuous on $(-2,2)$ and $\lim_{x \uparrow 2} f(x) = 2$,
$\lim_{x \downarrow 2} f(x) = -2$, so the series converges to $x$ for $x \in (-2,2)$ and converges to $0 $ for $x = \pm 2$.